# Fazer com que duas directives tenham o mesmo $scope no Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Tenho uma diretiva que gera um botão, e quando clico neste botão um contador aumenta 1.
Essa diretiva está inserida em dois lugares no meu index.html. 
Gostaria que quando eu clicasse em algum dos botões, os dois fossem alterados...

Segue o meu código:

**index.html:**

```
<div ng-app='demo'>
    <button-directive></button-directive>
    <button-directive></button-directive>
</div>
```

**app.js:**

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('buttonDirective', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-click="increment()">{{count}}</button>',
    }
});

demo.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.increment = function(){
        $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
    };
}]);
```

Aqui tem um fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dfalbel/1kyq5e15/

Comment: incrementei a resposta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sou muito experiente com angularjs, mas até onde eu sei o comportamento padrão de uma diretiva é compartilhar o scope do controller (do contrário precisamos criar um scope isolado).

Você está criando um novo controller pra cada diretiva.

Eu faria assim:

```
<div ng-app='demo' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button-directive></button-directive>
    <button-directive></button-directive>
</div>
```

js:

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('buttonDirective', function($parse) {    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-click="increment()">{{count}}</button>',
    }
});

demo.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.increment = function(){
        $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
    };
}]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rvnypx1c/3/

Mas veja que a diretiva ficou muito específica. Pra que fique mais genérica e possa ser reaproveitada, poderíamos fazer algo assim:

```
<div ng-app='demo' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button-directive ng-click="increment()" counter="{{count}}"></button-directive>
    <button-directive ng-click="increment()" counter="{{count}}"></button-directive>
    <button-directive ng-click="increment1()" counter="{{count1}}"></button-directive>
</div>
```

js:

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('buttonDirective', function($parse) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',        
        scope: {
            counter: '@'
        },
        template: '<button>{{counter}}</button>',
    }
});

demo.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.increment = function(){
        $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
    };

    $scope.count1 = 0;
    $scope.increment1 = function(){
        $scope.count1 = $scope.count1 + 1;
    };
}]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rvnypx1c/5/

Comment: você tem razão, eu queria fazer assim. o problema é que esses botões estão em lugares diferentes da minha página... não consigo colocá-los dentro do mesmo `div`.

Comment: você pode usar a div ou elemento que contém ambos, ou na pior hipótese o body. Defina esse controller lá que o scope vai ser compartilhado.

Comment: obrigado, consegui usando isso mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `$broadcast` do `$rootScope` para transmitir os eventos que desejar.

Código:

```
demo.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  $scope.increment = function ($broadcast) {
    $scope.count++;
    $broadcast('evento', $scope.count);
  }
}
```

Comment: desculpe, ainda não consegui fazer funcionar.. o que significa transmitir um evento?

Comment: Faz com que o evento seja enviado aos outros controllers, que podem receber o evento e ativar alguma função que receba esse evento.