# Primeira diretiva no angular

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando fazer uma diretiva simples no angularJS para exemplo.

Trata-se de um botão que recebe o nome da classe e o texto, da seguinte forma:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.alertar = function() {
        alert('alertando');
    }
}])

.directive('botao', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'js/diretivas/botao.html',
    scope: {
        classe: '=',
        texto: '='
    }
  };
});
```

Dentro de botao.html, tenho:

```
<button class="{{ classe }}">{{ texto }}</button>
```

Chamo a diretiva em index.html da seguinte forma:

```
<botao classe="btn" texto="Teste"></botao>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? O botão aparece, mas sem a classe e sem o texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para configurar as variaveis tem que ser com `@` [que vincula um atributo a propriedade do scope da directiva](https://www.slideshare.net/rodrigobranas/construindo-diretivas-com-angularjs), ***exemplo***:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.alertar = function() {
      alert('alertando');
    }    
  }])
  .directive('botao', function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<button class="{{classe}}">{{texto}}</button>',
      scope: {
        classe: '@',
        texto: '@'
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.class1 
{
  color:blue;
  width:150px;
  height: 30px;
}
.class2 
{
  color:red;
  width:150px;
  height: 30px;
}
.class3 
{
  color:yellow;
  width:150px;
  height: 30px;
}
.class4 
{
  color:orange;
  width:150px;
  height: 30px;
}
.class5 
{
  color:#111;
  width:150px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
  <botao classe="class1" texto="Botao Criado 1"></botao>
  <botao classe="class2" texto="Botao Criado 2"></botao>
  <botao classe="class3" texto="Botao Criado 3"></botao>
  <botao classe="class4" texto="Botao Criado 4"></botao>
  <botao classe="class5" texto="Botao Criado 5"></botao>
</div>
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [#AngularJS - angularjs-directive-manual](https://github.com/suissa/angularjs-directive-manual)
- [Fazer com que duas directives tenham o mesmo $scope no Angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54946/fazer-com-que-duas-directives-tenham-o-mesmo-scope-no-angular)
- [Construindo Diretivas com AngularJS](https://www.slideshare.net/rodrigobranas/construindo-diretivas-com-angularjs)